# How to add 1 sec to the date in golang?

Tags: go, time

How to add 1 sec to the date in golang ? I have:

```
t := time.Now().Format("2006/02/01 03:04:05")
```

and want something like below but so far getting *mismatched types string and time.Duration* error

```
t1, t2, t3 = t + 1*time.Second, t+3*time.Second, t+2*time.Second
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asigning a `string` to `t` (the result of calling `Format`) instead of a `Time` (the result of calling `Now`). Here's an working example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t.Format(time.RFC3339))

    t = t.Add(time.Second)
    fmt.Println(t.Format(time.RFC3339))
}

// prints
// 2017-01-21T16:51:31-05:00
// 2017-01-21T16:51:32-05:00
```

Answer (score 6):

```
func (t Time) Add(d Duration) Time
```

https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Add